# Trying to display output from an ArrayList in JTextArea

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm storing user input into an ArrayList of a class BarInfo. The class takes in multiple data: Strings, booleans, ints. Then I want to display the data stored in the order it was entered in a JTextArea. Now say the user inputs data for one bar with all the necessary information. When they display the data it works right. However, if more than one bar is inputted, or another bar is added afterwards, it displays multiple versions of the data with different data.

For example if two bars are entered the display will show both of the bars various times with different amounts of int data from both of them mixed, instead of just The first bar and then the second.

This is my class Bar:

```
class BarInfo
{
    private final String barLoc, barName, v="Vodka", w="Whiskey", r="Rum", 
            g="Gin", b="Brandy"; 
    private final boolean music, food;
    private final int vCount, wCount, rCount, gCount, bCount;

    public BarInfo(String l, String n, boolean m, boolean f, int v, int w,
                    int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.barLoc = l;
        this.barName = n;
        this.music = m;
        this.food = f;
        this.vCount = v;
        this.wCount = w;
        this.rCount = r;
        this.gCount = g;
        this.bCount = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "The bar is located at: " + barLoc + " \nThe bar is named: " + barName 
                + "\nLive Music: " + music + "\nFood Service: " + food + "\n"
                + "Liquor currently in stock (bottles):\n" + v + ": " +  vCount
                + "\n" + w + ": " + wCount + "\n" + r + ": " + rCount + "\n" 
                + g + ": " + gCount + "\n" + b + ": " + bCount + "\n\n";
    }

}
```

And my display code:

```
for(int i=0; i<barList.size(); i++)
        {
            jTextAreaDisplay.append(jTextAreaDisplay.getText() 
                    + barList.get(i).toString() + "\n\n");

        }
```

I'm guessing my for loop is somehow off, but I'm not seeing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE
Output expected for say 2 bars:

> The bar is located at: (barLoc)
>
> The bar is named: (barName)
>
> Live music: (true or false)
>
> Food Service: (true or false)
>
> Liquor currently in stock:
>
> Vodka = (amount)
>
> Whiskey = (amount)
>
> Rum = (amount)
>
> Gin = (amount)
>
> Brandy = (amount)

Then the second bar with its data. What I'm getting is like 6-7 different bars from those two bar inputs.

UPDATE SAMPLE OUTPUT from 2 bars entered:

```
The bar is located at: Kendall 
The bar is named: sgd
Live Music: false
Food Service: false
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 10
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0



The bar is located at: Kendall 
The bar is named: sgd
Live Music: false
Food Service: false
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 10
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0



The bar is located at: Kendall 
The bar is named: sgd
Live Music: false
Food Service: false
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 10
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0



The bar is located at: Kendall 
The bar is named: sgd
Live Music: false
Food Service: false
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 10
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0



The bar is located at: Kendall 
The bar is named: sgd
Live Music: false
Food Service: false
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 10
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0



The bar is located at: Kendall 
The bar is named: sgd
Live Music: false
Food Service: false
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 10
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0



The bar is located at: Miami Beach 
The bar is named: Wet
Live Music: true
Food Service: true
Liquor currently in stock (bottles):
Vodka: 20
Whiskey: 0
Rum: 0
Gin: 0
Brandy: 0
```

Comment: What output are you getting, and what output do you expect to get?

Comment: I updated the code above to show an example of output.

Comment: Are you certain that you aren't somehow entering the data into the ArrayList multiple times?  Also in your loop to add it, you are calling `JTextArea.append` which adds new text to the end of the area, but you are feeding it with the current text instead of just the new text.  That will cause the text to duplicate (but I'm not sure why your first bar is repeated six times instead of just twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTextArea.append()` *appends text*, so it's added to what is there already. Since you also append `jTextAreaDisplay.getText()` you'll get duplicates if the loop runs more than once.

Try:

```
for(BarInfo b : barList) { // Java foreach loop
    jTextAreaDisplay.append(b.toString() + "\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Okay, so something worked. Instead of 6 times I only got the first bar to repeat twice. PROGRESS!

Comment: That would coincide with the first bar being in the list twice. I suspected something more to be amiss ;)

Comment: Is there a way to check if jTextArea is empty before appended text to it? And if not then to clear the text?

Comment: The documentation page might be [useful](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) JTextArea extends [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html), which has getText and setText methods.